# App navigation only throw links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails, Is it possible to prevent HTTP requests that come from the **Browser's address bar** ? And only allow navigation through links made within the app ?

I really  looking for preventing a user to simply type his destination in the browser and only uses the links provided.

I know It maybe sounds silly. But I'm kind of trying to give a different UX than any regular website.

- Is this approach possible? And If yes, How?
- And what is the possible disadvantages or deficits that may cause?

Answer (score 1):

### No*.

You can make it harder for a user to guess the correct URL by using obfuscation or use sessions to make the application stateful. But technically a GET request sent by clicking a link or by typing the url in the browser are identical to the server. The former is a form of [security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

The whole basically violates the core tenants of what a RESTful application does. In REST a resource should be omnipotent - requesting the same resource should provide the same response no matter how the user got there.

If you find that an action should not be able to be performed by typing the address into the browser you are most likely using the HTTP verbs wrong (using GET where you should be using POST, PUT or DELETE) or have a poor authorization system.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Do you also think that this effect couldn't be done using JavaScript?

Comment: The question is not if it can be done - there are plenty of hacks that could make this possible. However its just a really bad idea. You'e looking for the wrong answers to the the wrong question - rethink what you are doing.

Comment: Excuse me for the misplaced expression, I meant that could this be done by using mush simpler approach like -maybe- disabling address bar using JavaScript.

Comment: No sensible browser will let you do that. At best you can open a popup without the address bar - which will cause issue with clients using blockers like AdBlock. Anytime you are trying to dictate exactly how users should use your app you are most likely building something which might impress the stakeholders when shown on your laptap but will fail dismally in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, **Yes**.

The previous responder is right, this sounds like a bad idea, but it is possible. I imagine it similar to how authentication work. Set a secret value in the session on the first page, ask for it it on the second page the user reaches, if they don't match user didn't use your navigation. Refresh as quickly as needed (every page, for example).

Drawbacks? It's weird, that's not how webpages work. A clicked link (or GET request) is not different than a URL typed in the browser. What do you mean by "different UX than any regular website", the more details we have the easier we can help.

Comment: Thank you, my application is meant to be used by only one user at the time, I was thinking of giving it more -Native App- ly experience also by forcing Fullscreen display

Comment: "forcing" will be hard unless you control the hardware, the user will do whatever they want (lesson learned). Even in that use case, a changing URL shouldn't affect the experience much. Speed will be a more important factor giving it a "Native App -ly" experience. Turbolinks might help, but you might want to go full JavaScript and build a JavaScript application instead.